# RTF hyperlink to component: open button grayed out

Tags: cme, rtf

While setting up a hyperlink to a component inside of a RTF, the "open" button to view the component is grayed out. Is this normal behavior? It seems like the button doesn't actually serve a purpose if it's always grayed out in this way. Users would need a way to easily see what the component values are.

[image: Hyperlink]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mine too is greyed out if I choose a `Component` as the link type.

However, the open button becomes enabled if using `http://` as the link type, and can be used to open the linked page (e.g. The BBC website) in a new browser tab.

[image]

Copying and pasting the TcmId of the Component (e.g. `tcm:234-122967`) into the search box is the only way I know of opening a linked Component.

If this is not a bug (or browser-specific anomaly), then having the open button open up the Component would be a good suggestion over at [SDL Web Ideas](https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/sdl_web_ideas/).

Comment: As suggested, this has been opened (by Travis) an idea over on the community site here: https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/sdl_web_ideas/i/sdl_web_general_suggestions/rtf-hyperlink-to-a-component-open-button

Comment: Looks like this idea has moved to https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/sdl_web_ideas/i/sdl-web-ideas/rtf-hyperlink-to-a-component-open-button